# Deploying a Google Cloud Function from a Source Repo using a custom repo folder path for the source code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-source-repos

#### What I want

I have my Source Repo set up (it mirrors a GitHub repo whose main branch is called `main`).
I'm trying to deploy a Python function, so I'm using a folder in the repo that contains a `main.py` and a `requirements.txt` file, as required [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#directory-structure-python).

I followed instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#gcloud_3) to build my `gcloud` deployment invocation.

In particular I'm interested in NOT using the root of the repo as the source directory. Here is an example command with actual values changed:

```
gcloud --project=my-project functions deploy my-function \
--gen2 \
--region=my-region \
--runtime=python311 \
--source=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/my-project/repos/my-repo/moveable-aliases/main/paths/my/source/directory/path/in/the/repo \
--entry-point=my_cloud_event_function_name \
--trigger-bucket=my-bucket
```

I expect this to work, given the following piece of documentation:

> To deploy from a revision other than master, append one of the following to the above path:

> /revisions/REVISION_NAME
> /moveable-aliases/MOVEABLE_ALIAS
> /fixed-aliases/FIXED_ALIAS

> To deploy source code from a directory other than the repository root, specify a revision, moveable alias, or fixed alias as above and append /paths/PATH_TO_YOUR_SOURCE_DIRECTORY to the path.

[source](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#from-source-repo)

#### HOWEVER this is what I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) Invalid Cloud Source Repository URL provided. 
Must match the following format: https://source.developers.google.com/projects/<projectId>/repos/<repoName>. 
Specify the desired branch by appending /moveable-aliases/<branchName>, the desired tag with /fixed-aliases/<tagName>, or the desired commit with /revisions/<commit>.
```

So no mention of the path in the repo to use something else than the root of the repo.

Am I missing anything here?

#### gcloud CLI version, in case that's relevant

```
gcloud --version

Google Cloud SDK 413.0.0
alpha 2023.01.06
beta 2023.01.06
bq 2.0.84
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.12
core 2023.01.06
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin 0.4.0
gsutil 5.17
```

Comment: Might not be useful at all. A few years ago (4 or 5) I used `revisions` with a commit hash - like ".../repos/repo-name/revisions/commit-hash/paths/..." I don't know if that can be used these days, or if you can use it in your case.

Comment: It should be possible, as per the doc quoted above. I just tried it however and I run into the same issue, where it appears that the non-root path specified after `/paths/` is simply not supported.

Comment: It turns out that from the GCP Console UI I can edit a Cloud Function deployment and select a folder path within the source repo. 
I'm not sure why this won't work from the CLI tool, and configuring things by clicking around in a UI isn't the most reproducible way to set things up so I might end up using something else.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @HugoMailhot

> It turns out that from the GCP Console UI I can edit a Cloud Function deployment and select a folder path within the source repo. I'm not sure why this won't work from the CLI tool, and configuring things by clicking around in a UI isn't the most reproducible way to set things up so I might end up using something else.

---

Reference:

- [Deploy a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#console)